# Agregar opciones a una lista desplegable mediante un imput

Tags: javascript, html5, input, html-select, innerhtml

Básicamente tendría una lista desplegable

```html
<label for="productos" class="text-center">Seleccione un producto:</label>
  <select onchange="myFunction()" id="sel" required>
    <option value="">...
    <option value="Aceite"> Aceite
    <option value="Arroz importado"> Arroz importado
    <option value="Arroz nacional"> Arroz nacional
    <option value="Azucar blanca"> Azucar blanca
</select>
```

y 2 imputs debajo, uno para el nombre y otro para el valor

```
<label name="nombre">Nombre :</label>
<input type="text" required>

<label name="valor">Valor :</label>
<input type="text" required>
```

Mediante los cuales se pudiera introducir el nombre de la opción a agregar y su valor correspondiente, y un botón para agregar esa opción a la lista desplegable.

Estoy pensando en una función javascript que me permita agregar el nombre y el valor almacenados en una variable cada uno y luego con `innerHTML` introducirlo como tal en la lista del html, alguna ayuda o idea de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: No se entiende que es esto: un comentario? Un post de lo quedas haciendo? No tiene nada de pregunta sobre un problema de código a resolver. Esto no es una pregunta verificable con problema de codigo, ni códigos. Ni siquiera se puede saber que problemas tienes.

Comment: Debes saber que para hacer una pregunta, lee [ask] y como hacer un [example], debes plantear tu trabajo, agregar tu código de trabajo con el error o problemas, y plantear lo que se quiere lograr.

Comment: @elfuturo-llego No toques el código del OP (no me refiero a darle formato, sino a agregar etiquetas que anteriormente no estaban, en este caso).

Comment: @padaleiana las unicas que agregue fueron las etiquetas de cierre de los options, porque me parecia mas comodo para manejar el texto que tienen dentro, pero como prefieras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asocias una función al evento 'click' de un `<button>`, y dentro de esa función creas el `<option>`, recuperas los valores de los 2 inputs y lo agregas como propiedades del `<option>` para finalmente colocarlo al final del `<select>`

```js
function createOption(){ // creamos un nodo <option></option> con los valores de los inputs y lo hacemos hijo del select justo al final del resto sus nodos hijos
  let option = document.createElement('option');
  let label = document.createTextNode(`${document.getElementById('input_name').value}`)
  option.value = document.getElementById('input_value').value;
  option.appendChild(label);
  document.getElementById('sel').appendChild(option);
  console.log(option)
}

document.getElementById('create_option').addEventListener('click',createOption) // al clickear el boton llamamos a la funcion
```

```html
<label for="productos" class="text-center">Seleccione un producto:</label>
<select id="sel" required>
  <option value="">...</option>
  <option value="Aceite"> Aceite </option>
  <option value="Arroz importado"> Arroz importado </option>
  <option value="Arroz nacional"> Arroz nacional </option>
  <option value="Azucar blanca"> Azucar blanca </option>
</select>
  
<label name="nombre">Nombre :</label>  
<input type="text" id="input_name" required>

<label name="valor">Valor :</label> 
<input type="text" id="input_value" required>

<button id="create_option" type="button">CREATE</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es exactamente lo que quería 